# Using implicit differentiation to solve a function and stuck at factoring out y'.

Tags: derivatives, factoring, implicit-differentiation

So here is the question:

$$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)=\frac{\pi x}{y^2} $$

When I solved it implicitly I got (with much pain in formatting it on this site :P):

$$ y^2=\pi \left(\frac{y^2-2xy\cdot y'}{y^4}\right)\cdot \left ( \sec^2\left(\frac{2x}{y}\right)\cdot (2y-2xy') \right ) $$

Now I know this sounds stupid but I don't know how to factor out y' because apparently I have derived correctly to the best of my knowledge and yet when I input (1,2) in my function and then check Wolphram Alpha, I get two different results (that shouldn't be the case)....

I'm at a loss as to what to do... Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thanks, I thought It would be better to write it like this so that it is more readable...

Comment: Did you start by rearranging to give $$\frac{2x}{y}=tan\left(\frac{\pi x}{y^2}\right)?$$

Comment: no, I changed tan^-1 into 1/tan... Now that you mentioned it, I'm gonna try doing that... Thanks

Comment: So now my function after implicitly deriving it, is: $$ \frac{2y-2x\cdot y'}{y^2}=sec^2(\frac{\pi x}{y^2})\cdot \pi (\frac{y^2-2xy\cdot y'}{y^4}) $$

Comment: I did it! I got it thanks to that simple method of solving it! Thank you @bluesh34

Comment: Note also that $\tan^{-1}$ typically does *not* mean $1/\tan$, but rather the inverse (arc) tangent. If you started by transforming $\tan^{-1} \to 1/\tan$ that might explain how you got a wrong answer.

Comment: Really? Why is it like that? I was always under the impression that a^-1 really means 1/a...

Comment: No probs @SCS: $a^{-1}$ does mean $1/a$, but $tan^{-1}$ doesn't mean $\frac {1}{tan}$ but rather the inverse of tan. What about $(tan x)^{-1}$? I'll leave that to you to research, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Write your problem as $F[x,y]=0$ and perform total differentiation.

So $$0 = dF = (dF/dx) dx + (dF/dy) dy$$ and then
$$y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{dF/dx}{dF/dy}$$

Comment: @user376343. Thanks for editing !

Comment: I´ve edited more than this one, but I stop now :)

Comment: @user376343. This was at the time I became a user. It took me a lot of time to learn MathJax (I am blind). Cheers :-)

Comment: I understand. My greatest admirations to you, dear Claude.